# Can I forward a REST request to another resource?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, kotlin, multipartform-data

I use:

- Spring Boot
- Kotlin
- Spring MVC

One micro-service sends a ***multipart/form-data*** using REST to another micro-service (A -> C). I need to implement a security-gateway between those two micro-services (A -> B -> C)
Can I just forward a request to another micro-service? (B -> C)
All I need is to read just one param ***tenant-id*** from those params:

A multipart form submit with the following parts:

```
deployment-name ----- text/plain 
enable-duplicate-filtering ----- text/plain 
deploy-changed-only ----- text/plain 
deployment-source ----- text/plain 
tenant-id ----- text/plain 
* ----- application/octet-stream
```

That's simple with the following Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/data/deployment/create")
    fun uploadDmn(
            @RequestParam("tenant-id")
            tenantId: String
    ) {
        println(tenantId)
    }
```

But how can I forward that request without reading it? Because I have no idea how I can read the last one param (`* ----- application/octet-stream`)

Comment: Making use of Zuul

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can forward one request to another.
First you need to register your services to discover server there are many options 
you can use eureka link is given below

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka

Then use a API gateway for redirecting services and security

Example is given in below link

https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-communication-zuul-api-gateway-1

Answer (score 0):

For redirect or forward you should use zuul gateway. Zuul can redirect your requests directly or using eureka discovery service.
For inner microservices communication, you can use Spring Rest Template, or Netflix feign.
Please have a look an example project in my github
[spring cloud microservices](https://github.com/armdev/microservices-security)